# Sony Smartwatch 2 manage vibration on receiving notification

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I'm using sony addon sdk to develop an notification app on smart watch 2.

I've managed to get everything work (watch vibrates when my phone gets notification),
but I havn't got a way to modify the vibration length.

Is there any way to manage vibration on receiving notification? as in shorter vibration, longer vibration, etc..

The default vibration seem a bit too long, so I want to modify it's length.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: There is no possibility to configure the vibration of the standard notification, using Notification API.

You can only create custom vibration pattern, in your SmartWatch2 extension using Control API. That is available only after user starts Extension, not for the Notification purpose. To start vibration pattern for your running extension, you can use: `ControlExtension.startVibrator(int onDuration, int offDuration, int repeats)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll have to stick with the default vibration then .